# Android: positioning of Floating Action Button unpredictable

Tags: android, xamarin.android, floating-action-button

Some of my **floating action buttons** don't remain where I want, and I cannot understand why.
[image]
The first is how they should be (and actually sometimes it works), the other two images show how they behave sometimes... and I cannot find a "pattern" in this behavior.

This is the layout (only one half):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lay_attivita_edit_ubicazioni"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding_lateral"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding_lateral">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/container_attivita_edit_origini">
            <TextView
                style="@style/FieldLabel"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/attivita_edit_origini" />
            <ListView
                style="@style/ListView"
                android:id="@+id/list_attivita_edit_origini"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:background="@drawable/border_rectangle" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        style="@style/FloatingActionButton.Small"
        android:id="@+id/fab_attivita_edit_ubicazioni_edit_origini"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/list_attivita_edit_origini"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried also to se `anchor` and `anchorGravity` programmatically but the result is the same. It could happen because depending on some logic one of the two sections could not be visible, in case I make them invisible at the end of `OnCreateView`.

It doesn't depend on the visibility of the "anchor list" because the fab move even if I always leave both the lists visible.
I tried also to change programmatically anchor and anchorId of the fab at every change of visibility of them or of their lists, nothing.

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams editOrigineFabParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)editOrigineFab.LayoutParameters;
editOrigineFabParams.AnchorId = Resource.Id.list_attivita_edit_origini;
editOrigineFabParams.AnchorGravity = (int)(GravityFlags.Top | GravityFlags.Right | GravityFlags.End);
editOrigineFab.LayoutParameters = editOrigineFabParams;
```

With the same conditions/code sometimes they work and sometimes they don't. It looks like a bug in Android. I tried with Android 7.0 and 7.1, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.25.3.1.
Anyone who had a similar problem or who has an idea of what could be the reason?

Comment: If you change the visibility of your FAB anchor view, the button will move. If you don't want it to move, make sure it's anchor view keeps the same width.

Comment: @AlexandreBOURETZ so you think that it's because when I hide the containers of the lists I set at zero their widths and heights? I try, thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome let me know if it works.

Comment: @AlexandreBOURETZ I tried every kind of combination, also leaving always there both the lists, every time I change visibility of the fab they move randomly. I'll update a bit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use FAB by james montemagno.

Add FAB by james montemagno from nuget to your project.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.FloatingActionButton/

```
<Refractored.Fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"
        app:app_colorNormal="@color/primary"
        app:app_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
        app:app_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll do an attempt. Before I'm trying to update all my packages and maybe I'll try to use also Android 7.1, just to understand if it's a bug of the Android fab.

Comment: Useful answer because you gave me an alternative, but I wasted one hour trying to make it working, I always have the problem "Didn't find class "Refractored.Fab.FloatingActionButton" on path: DexPathList". I gave up, this component is quite old and I would prefer to remain on the standard if possible.

Comment: you are getting that error because you have not included that component from nuget to your project.

Comment: I have posted another answer with the standard floating action button. Always use layout_gravity for positioning any component.

Comment: I included the package, by the way I wasted more than one hour to use a component that I don't want to use...

Answer (score 0):

use layout_gravity for positioning .

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
   android:id="@+id/fab"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
   android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" / >
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried every combination of layout_gravity and/or layout_anchorGravity. The bug has a behavior completely not deterministic. Probably there is something wrong in how I'm using it in the fragment lifecycle. Thank you anyway.

Comment: completely remove your FAB code and paste this code.It is working on my system.

Comment: Probably I haven't explained well... my layout works, at the beginning and most of the times. But when I relayout my fragments inside a tabbed panel some of them move in the wrong place, but only sometimes.